# Open Apple Maps by tapping on a WKInterfaceMap in a dynamic notification

Tags: apple-push-notifications, watchkit, apple-watch, apple-maps, watchos

My Watch app receives push notifications containing location information and I use that info to show a `WKInterfaceMap`.

However, when I tap on the map in the notification dynamic interface, my app is opened instead of the Maps app.

I found [this forum post](https://devforums.apple.com/message/1102120#1102120) stating:

> There is no url to call at this time. The user tapping on a WKInterfaceMap object is the only way to launch the Maps app from yours.

Does anyone know why this does not work with `WKInterfaceMap` objects in a notification?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since notifications are not interactive, it's not possible to trigger any object interaction in a dynamic notification. Tapping anywhere in the notification area will always launch your watch app.

This is briefly mentioned in the [App Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/watchos/documentation/General/Conceptual/WatchKitProgrammingGuide/CustomzingthePushNotificationInterface.html), under Designing Your Dynamic Interface:

> Tapping your notification interface launches the app, so notification interfaces should not contain interactive controls.